# Can't redirect STDERR or STDOUT to file

Tags: gnu-screen, stdout, stderr

I have application written in `Go` language and it runs in `screen`
(I do not think problem relates to `Go` language. I believe it uses `STDOUT` and `STDERR`)

```
screen -S log_server -d -m go run log_server.go 2 > err3.txt 1 > std3.txt
```

When it crashes I get error written in screen not in `err3.txt` or `std3.txt`

`screen` does not scroll and does not allow me to read full error.

`std3.txt` works properly
`err3.txt` has size 0 and error is printed in `screen` (I can see last 20 or 30 lines) 
App crashes once per 3 or 5 days.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not all spaces are permissible.  Try instead

```
screen -S log_server -d -m go run log_server.go 2> err3.txt 1> std3.txt
```

Comment: Thank You. I ran command as you advised. `std3.txt` worked for me. So I thought these spaces are Ok.

Comment: Nope.  But `> std3.txt` is a lawful form of `1> std3.txt`, so redirecting STDOUT was working, and the rest of the stuff was just creating errors or being ignored as extra arguments to the main command.  By the way, and forgive me for saying this, but feel free to ACCEPT the answer if you're happy with it.

Comment: I  planned to mark answer accepted once process will crash and I will get error in file. But it is not a problem. Thank You for you response. I am happy with your answer. It is accepted.